# Box and Give Equation Number to a multiline mathematical equation

Tags: equations, box

```
$I(a_1,a_2,a_3)=\displaystyle{\int\limits_{c_1-i\infty}^{c_1+i\infty}\mathrm{\frac{dz_1}{2\pi i}}\, \, \cdots\int\limits_{c_5-i\infty}^{c_5+i\infty}\mathrm{\frac{dz_5}{2\pi i}}(Q^2)^{z_1}(M^2)^{z_2}
\left\langle a_1+z_3 \right\rangle \left\langle a_2+z_{14} \right\rangle \left\langle a_3+z_{125} \right\rangle \left\langle d/2+z_{1345} \right\rangle}$
\begin{flushright}
$\displaystyle{\cdot\frac{\Gamma(-z_1) \Gamma(-z_2)\Gamma(-z_3)}{\Gamma(a_1)\Gamma(a_2)\Gamma(z_1+d/2)}}$\\
\end{flushright}
```

Comment: please extend your code fragment to complete but small document beginning with `\documentclas{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. preamble should contain only to your problem relevant packages. explain, where you like to have box? welcome to tex.se!

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

Some suggestions and comments:

- Do familiarize yourself with the `amsmath` package and, in particular, the multiline displayed-equation environments provided by this package. For your equation, I'd like to suggest a `split` environment embedded in an `equation` environment. The `equation` environment provides the equation number, and the `split` environment lets you introduce line splits and provide alignment points.
- Don't overuse `\left`, `\right`, and `\limits`. In fact, these directives are not needed here if you set up the correct math environments.
- Unless the textblock of your environment is unusually wide, it's necessary to make the equation span three rows, not just two.
- Use the `\boxed` macro, also provided by the `amsmath` package, to draw a rectangular box around the equation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\boxed" macro and "split" env.
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\boxed{%
\begin{split}
I(a_1,a_2,a_3)
&=\int_{c_1-i\infty}^{c_1+i\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}z_1}{2\pi i} \,\dotsi
  \int_{c_5-i\infty}^{c_5+i\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}z_5}{2\pi i} 
  \times(Q^2{)}^{z_1}(M^2{)}^{z_2}\\
&\quad\times
  \langle a_1+z_3     \rangle 
  \langle a_2+z_{14}  \rangle 
  \langle a_3+z_{125} \rangle 
  \langle d/2+z_{1345}\rangle \\
&\quad\times\frac{\Gamma(-z_1)\Gamma(-z_2)\Gamma(-z_3)}{
  \Gamma(a_1)\Gamma(a_2)\Gamma(z_1+d/2)}
\end{split}
} % end of \boxed
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```